# How to add a static parent node to telerik MVC treeview it's possible

Tags: c#

I am binding a tree view to a model. I want to add a 'static' parent node. Is that possible?

Here is code I am using now.

```
@(Html.Telerik().TreeView()
    .Name("secteurActivite")
    .ShowCheckBox(true)
    .ExpandAll(false)
    .ShowLines(true)
    .BindTo(Model.secteurActivites, mappings =>
    {
        mappings.For<SecteurActivite>(binding => binding
            .ItemDataBound((item, secteur) =>
            {

                item.Text = secteur.Nom;
                item.Value = secteur.SecteurActiviteId.ToString();
                if (secteur.SecteurActiviteParentId != null)
                {
                    item.ImageUrl = "~/Content/Images/document.bmp";
                }
                else
                {
                    item.ImageUrl = "~/Content/Images/folder.bmp";
                }                        
            })
            .Children(secteur => secteur.SecteurActivite1));                
    })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a new class called Root...

```cs
public class Root {
  public IEnumerable<SecteurActivite> SecteurActivites { get;set; }
}
```

Then, instead of the secteurActivites list on the model, make it a list of 1 Root object...

```cs
public IEnumerable<Root> SecteurActivites = 
    new List<Root> { 
        new Root { SecteurActivites = secteurActivites } 
    };
```

Then, add another mapping for Root:

```cs
mappings.For<Root>(binding => binding
            .ItemDataBound((item, root) =>
            {
                item.ImageUrl = "~/Content/Images/folder.bmp";
            })
            .Children(root => root.SecteurActivites));
```

Hope this helps.